# Switch Shrink and Expand based on REFLECTX

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I am using XMonad.Layout.Reflect together with XMonad.Layout.MultiToggle to flip my layout left-right when needed. However, when any layout is reflected, my keybinds for shrinking and expanding the layout, eg.

...

```
((modm,  xK_h), sendMessage Shrink),
((modm,  xK_l), sendMessage Expand),
```

...

behaves as they are inversed.

So, what I want is a way to remap my keys, or maybe use a function instead of sendMessage that somehow detects the state of the layout and chooses Shrink/Expand depending on that.

Now I know that checking eg. global state variables (of which there are no such thing I guess) is not very Haskelly, so I am at a little bit of a loss on how to do this. I've considered XMonad.Actions.PerWorkspaceKeys, but it seems to do a match against the entire Workspace name. Another route could be to add/delete keybinds in defaultConfig, but again - I'm not sure this is even doable (it seems messy anyways).

Any ideas on how to approach this anyone? I know Haskell on the level of having read the "Learn you a Haskell..." book from beginning to end and making smallish programs based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using the layout description to find out whether it has been reflected, following [this blog post by Thomas Churchman](https://churchman.nl/2019/06/17/xmonad-per-layout-keybindings/):

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as S
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

getActiveLayoutDescription :: X String
getActiveLayoutDescription = do
    workspaces <- gets windowset
    return $ description . S.layout . S.workspace . S.current $ workspaces
```

The key bindings would then look like this:

```
((modm,  xK_h), do
    layoutDesc <- getActiveLayoutDescription
    if "ReflectX" `isInfixOf` layoutDesc
        then sendMessage Expand
        else sendMessage Shrink
,
((modm,  xK_l), do
    layoutDesc <- getActiveLayoutDescription
    if "ReflectX" `isInfixOf` layoutDesc
        then sendMessage Shrink
        else sendMessage Expand
    ),
```

---

Side notes:

> my keybinds for shrinking and expanding the layout [...] behaves as they are inversed.

While what you want to do makes perfect sense, it is worth mentioning that this behaviour happens because reflecting a layout will also reflect the position of the master pane. Since `Shrink` and `Expand` act on the master pane, they will appear to be inverted, as far as absolute horizontal coordinates go, if you are using a layout like `Tall`, in which the master pane is on the left of the screen. Different layouts might be affected differently.

> Now I know that checking eg. global state variables (of which there are no such thing I guess) is not very Haskelly, so I am at a little bit of a loss on how to do this.

This approach is not unthinkable, and [`XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Util-ExtensibleState.html) is meant for setting up this sort of thing. In this case, though, I feel using a stateful flag is be way more trouble than it's worth.